# What templating languages are available for both Java and Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, templates, frontend

I'm looking for a templating language that I can use to generate html on both the server, using java, and in a web browser using javascript.  I want to use the same template in both situations.  It needs to support i18n and if it can tie into Spring that would be awesome.  I've seen mustache but are there any others available?

Comment: Have a look at Google's [Closure Templates](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could go with [{{mustache}}](http://mustache.github.com/).  It's available in pretty much everything under the sun.  It's also pretty popular.

Here's a great example of usage (taken from the mustache site)...

```
{{#items}}
Name: {{name}}
Price: {{price}}
  {{#features}}
  Feature: {{description}}
  {{/features}}
{{/items}}
```

We have many items that contain a name, price and many features that contain a description.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with mustache.java https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java and Hogan.js http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/.

Comment: Awesome. Good luck on your project.

Comment: what about handlebars or dust?

Comment: I actually use handlebars now and not mustache (this is a two year old answer). I don't think Dust would work for this as to my knowledge there is no Java version of Dust.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but take a look at [Casper](http://code.google.com/p/casper/).

[Casper User Guide](http://code.google.com/p/casper/wiki/UserGuide)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this would suit all your needs, but you could look into [json-templates](http://code.google.com/p/json-template/). It mainly advertises support for JavaScript and Python, but there is also some Java code in its source repository.